# Applying Individual Conditional Formatting in VBA -- VERY SLOW

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

Due to the limitations of databars (i.e. they cannot use relative references for the mins and maxes, I'm adding an individual), I'm adding an individual conditional format rule to each cell (selection is 13 columns wide) in 810 rows.

Unfortunately, this operation takes ~35 minutes on an i5 4670k. A number of other operations take place in the macro I'm running, but I've isolated the speed issue to the application of conditional formatting.

Does anyone have any suggestions for speeding up the code? Here is the stripped down version of the program.

```
for RowCounter = FirstRow to Lastrow

for i = 0 to 12

' Add Databars
Range(FirstColumn & RowCounter).Offset(0, 2 * i).FormatConditions.AddDatabar
With Range(FirstColumn & RowCounter).Offset(0, 2 * i).FormatConditions(1)
    .MinPoint.Modify xlConditionValueNumber, 0
    .MaxPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueNumber, newvalue:= _
        Range(FirstColumn & RowCounter).Offset(0, 2 * i + 1).Value
End With

Next i

Next RowCounter
```

edit 2: as requested, here is a screenshot[image: Here's what I want]

Essentially, there are two types of columns. Columns that need to be formatted (green), and columns on which the formatting will be based (yellow). For every row, I'm looking at every other column (in this case I'm apply formatting only to the green columns -- hence the i * 2 offset). Sometimes I want to apply conditional formatting (if the value in the cell isn't blank or a date) to the cell. If I do, I want to apply a databar with the maximum based on the cell immediately to the right (the yellow column). Eventually, the yellow columns will just be hidden.

edit 3: I've found the solution (see below). The issue was with a part of the code that was deleting cells. With such a large amount of conditional formatting rules, this slows down any cell deletion considerably, causing the program to run very, very slowly.

Comment: Is it possible to just copy the format of the first line to the other 809 rows ? Also, it would help if you turned off calculations and screen updating before executing your macro. Also, make sure that you do clear all previous format conditions beforehand. Too many junk format conditions can 1) result in the wrong format and 2) break your workbook.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't just copy the formatting, as the Max References are absolute. Also, I have some logic that applies, so not every one of the 13 cells gets the conditional formatting. I've already turned off calculation and screen updating. That's in the full version of the macro (I figured it was too large to include the whole thing). Finally, I am starting with a fresh sheet every time the macro runs. The entire sheet is deleted beforehand.

Comment: These many cells shouldn't take long at all to refresh. The problem seems to be something else. Can you pls post a screenshot and a very simple example of the formatting you eventually want, e.g. cell (i, B)'s databar's min is from cell (i, C) and max from cell (i, D), etc.

Comment: Done. Please let me know if there's any other information you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured out the solution.

The first step in the procedure is the deletion of a number of cells.

The second step is applying ~5000 conditional formatting rules (to each individual cell).

Trying to delete cells with all those rules still applying is miserably slow. Thus, the best way to code this is to do all of the cell deletion first, then apply all conditional formatting at the end of the program.